# Celery doesn't run task

Tags: django, redis, celery

Help me, please, to understand what I am doing wrong. Celery doesn't run my task.

```
Settings.py
CELERY_BROKER_URL = 'redis://localhost:6379'
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'redis://localhost:6379'
CELERY_ACCEPT_CONTENT = ['application/json']
CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_RESULT_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_TIMEZONE = TIME_ZONE
```

proj/celery.py

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
import os
from celery import Celery
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'proj.settings') 

app = Celery('proj')
app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings', namespace='CELERY')
app.autodiscover_tasks()
```

**init**.py

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals
from celery import app as celery_app   
__all__ = ['celery_app']
```

Code

```
@shared_task
def generate(instance, sender, **kwargs):
    for i in CK_PROGRAM_NAME:
        program_kf = i[0]
        ck = instance.dk*program_kf
        program_name = i[1]
        program_obj = Program.objects.get(name=program_name)
        foodprogram_generator(instance, ck, program_kf, program_obj, sender, **kwargs)
    return

@receiver(post_save, sender=LeadUser)
def leaduser_foodprogram_post_save(instance, sender, **kwargs):
    generate.delay(instance, sender, **kwargs)
    return
```

Worker is run by: celery -A proj worker --loglevel=INFO

The logic is: 
after client_object is created, post_save signal starts leaduser_foodprogram_post_save, that adds to a queue generate()

I can see result, so I think it is not run. 
Without celery everything works properly.

Thanks for you answers!

Comment: Does autodiscovery work? http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/reference/celery.html#celery.Celery.autodiscover_tasks

Comment: Well, I think is does, it finds tasks: http://joxi.ru/DmBD17Yfwb0W9A

Comment: I am not that familiar with Django. Have you checked receiver also? Is it run (imported?) in Django? (Is it what you mean by 'Without celery everything works properly.'?)

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things:: 
* the config_from_object with namespace might strip that from the variables, so you might not get what u want as a configuration, 
* when you see shared task you need to make sure you are calling the task from the configured celery app, as the main point of using shared task is to actually share tasks between different apps. Have a look at the "set_default" function on the celery app object, by just calling that on the celery setup you should see a difference.
Anyway best way to check is to put rdb in there and inspect the celery app, check the configuration and if the broker is not set then the second point explained on my previous comment should get you going